# Fibonacci Spiral - Robocode

Tags: java, fibonacci, spiral, robocode

Does anyone know how I could make a spiral motion following the Fibonacci pattern around a point in Robocode? I have methods like setTurnRight (double), setAhead (double), getX () and getY ().

I tried to make a simple spiral, without the required standard, that way, but it did not work ... It was more like a circle.

```
this.setAhead(this.direction * Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY);
if (this.direction == 1) {
    this.setTurnRight(Utils.normalRelativeAngleDegrees(this.enemy.getBearing() + 60));
} else {
    this.setTurnRight(Utils.normalRelativeAngleDegrees(this.enemy.getBearing() + 120));
}
```

physics of the game:
http://robowiki.net/wiki/Robocode/Game_Physics

Comment: To draw a spiral, you have to gradually increase the radius.  http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fibonacci/fibnat.html#spiral

Comment: But add how much? and how often?

Comment: Read the post I linked.

Comment: I think `x = sin(t)`, `y = cos(t)` , and `z = t` will make a spiral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Robocode Logarithmic Spiral

Here is a working run method to make a bot follow a logarithmic spiral and I believe it is a close approximation of the golden spiral (which is the spiral that can be approximated with the Fibonacci numbers).

```
    public void run() {
      double v = 5;
      double c = Math.PI*2;
      double a = .1;
      double b = .0053468;

      setMaxVelocity(v);
      setAhead(100*999);
      setTurnRight(360*999);
      while(true)
      {
          double t = getTime();
          double f = a*Math.pow(Math.E,b*t);
          double w = v/(c*f);       

          setMaxTurnRate(w);
          execute();
          System.out.println(t+"\t"+w);
      }
    }
```

### Explanation

To move in a circle (trivial spiral), you keep constant *speed* (how fast the bot is moving) and constant *revolution speed* (how fast the bot is turning). There are several ways to go from this trivial spiral movement to something more interesting. **The simplest way to move in a spiral is to keep constant speed and vary the revolution speed.** [This](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/16756) answer from the game development exchange gives a good walk through on how to get an approximate equation for revolution speed.

- `w = v / (2*pi*t)` or `w = v / (2*pi*f(t))` where:

  - **w** = revolution speed
  - **v** = speed
  - **pi** = 3.14...
  - **t** = time or **f(t)** = function of the radius over time

This equation gives a way to move along a spiral and we can choose any spiral we want by specifying a **f(t)**. To get the correct radius function for the golden spiral, check out [this](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Golden_spiral) wiki page about the golden spiral. It gives this equation:

- `r = a*e^(b*theta)` or in other words `f(t) = a*e^(b*t)` where:

  - **f(t)** = our radius function
  - **a** = arbitrary constant for scaling the spiral
  - **e** = Euler's constant
  - **b** = .0053468 (or .3063489 if using radians)
  - **t** = time

### Conclusion

All that is left is to incorporate this code into your bot and choose your own values for **a** and **v**. *v* will determine the speed of the bot, so a larger *v* is a good idea (max is 10) and since the max for *w* is 8, you should scale *a* accordingly so that *w* stays between 0 and 8 for as long as possible (which is why I've included the println).

**[NOTE:** I couldn't think of an easy way to superimpose the golden spiral on the bot's path to check it's accuracy. So while it is clearly a logarithmic spiral, I am unsure to what degree it approximates the desired golden spiral **]**